# "Passive voice" versus "passive construction" versus "passive sentence" versus "passive form"

Tags: passive-voice

I've been living in japan so long I don't remember how to speak English.
On some websites the authors uses the phrase "passive form" 
http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html.
While here I often read *passive construction* or *passive voice* but in highschool I never heard the phrase *passive voice*. The teacher only ever described a sentence as passive or active. I didn't hear that there was such a thing as passive *voice* until I began studying ancient Greek and had no idea that English verbs in the passive ***_*_** could be referee to as being in the passive voice but. Can I also use the word *passive* as a noun?

Ie. This verb is written in the passive.

Comment: Also, can I say "to be stopped is the 'passive' of "to stop" ?

Comment: I think I'm beginning to see that in English since we use several words to create a passive or negative meaning, it is more proper to say "passive / negative construction" when referring to English grammar. But...

Comment: When referring to grammar in another language where they don't use a construction of more than one word to create passive or negative meaning , it is more proper to refer to the word as being in the "negative form" for example in Japanese we say ikanai is the negative form of iku. I'm this sentence I would not say "ikanai" is the negative construction/voice of "iku" because it is only one word. Right?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, it doesn't matter terribly much whether you say "a passive verb" or "a verb in the passive" or "a verb in the passive voice" or "a verb with a passive construction". (Strictly, there isn't necessarily just one passive construction, e.g. you might say that "They were hurt" and "They got hurt" are two different passive constructions.)